# How can we update UWP application run on raspberry pi 3 remotely from Azure Iot hub?

Tags: uwp, raspberry-pi3, azure-iot-hub, windows-10-iot-core, azure-iot-hub-device-management

I have created **UWP c# application** that run on **Raspberry pi 3** with **windows 10 Iot core OS**.It has program that read sensor data and send data to Azure.We want to make sure that once it deploy to customer location we would be able to **manage and update application** remotely.We have build our iot solution using **Azure Iot central**.

We have checked below options for automatic device management article from **Microsoft MSDN** site but those are put us in confusion and do not have any real time sample and suggest lengthy  process of registering and certified solution  application package on store and provide update to device

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-automatic-device-management
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-csharp-csharp-device-management-get-started

We want simple,clear and professional approach to **update remote device** achieve this so in the future we can support multiple tenant and do not to go for Microsoft store registration approach

Comment: Not sure what you mean. You cannot deploy a new assembly to your device or install new software on it once it is in the field afaik. What you can do is ]manage its configuratuion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-central/howto-manage-devices#change-a-device-setting). If you need to auto update the software I think you need to program that into your application.

Comment: Thank you for reply.I do not need auto update I want to push it to device group when it would require from Azure.I tried to install IOT edge run time but it is not compatible with raspberry pi3.Now i m not sure which way i will follow from suggested in this link.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/service/iot/updating-iot-core-apps#using-oma-dm

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Windows Azure DM Client](https://github.com/ms-iot/iot-core-azure-dm-client) to update your UWP app. Azure IoT Device Management allows you to update software remotely without the need to have local, physical access to the device. Firstly, you need to upload the new version application into a blob storage, the device client needs to connect the Azure IoT Hub, and then you can use a portal or an application to remote upgrade the application.

Comment: Above one is good example but It has some c++ code.I am not familiar with c++ .it would be very difficult to trouble shoot issue in the production for us

Comment: Sorry,i  can only find this sample which is provided by Microsoft.  Which language did you want? You can post a feedback in the repo.